# Application status monitoring in websphere

Tags: api, websphere

is there a way to interact with websphere 6.1 from a servlet to check if an application is running ? If so, is such transaction too resource-consuming operation to do it let's say before an "index" page is loaded ?.

The java.net.URL approach is simpler but discarded.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to know if an WebApp is running from a Servlet? If you are inside your servlet this mean your app is Running. Also, it depends what you mean by running: The App Server is running, The DB is responding, etc.
Any way, you could check the Perf Servlet, this might help you: http://hostname/wasPerfTool/servlet/perfservlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the mbean/jmx interface: search for this infocenter topic in your release: tjmx_updating_app.html